# removeEventListener is not working (function is not anonymous, exactly the same as addEventListener!!)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, removeeventlistener

I have trawled every single post saying that removeEventListener is not working. 99% of them are because the function being removed does not match the created function. But in my case the functions are **exactly** the same, yet the event isn't being removed at all when it is supposed to.

The idea is that when component state `isOpen[1]===true` the event listener should just bugger off. But it's not. Nothing I do seems to make removeEventListener work!! I have logged everywhere in the component and everything is happening in the right sequence. `useEffect` is receiving the correct signal at the correct time to activate `removeEventListener`, but the listener remains!!

Please help. Going mad.

**UPDATE: after all of the advice this is the current code. Not much has changed, but I have tried all of your solutions (thank you)**

```js
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(["", false]);
  const [panelHeight, setPanelHeight] = useState({ skills: 0, contact: 0 });
  const [envOpen, setEnvOpen] = useState(false);
  const [scrollState, setScrollState] = useState("show");

  // HIDE NAVBUTTONS ON DOWN SCROLL, REVEAL ON UP SCROLL

  var lastScrollTop = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollTop;

  function scrollDetect() {
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("show");
    } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("hide");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
  }

  const setOpen = ([title, state]) => {
    let newState = !state;
    setIsOpen([title, newState]);
  };

  const setHeight = (title, height) => {
    setPanelHeight((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [title]: height }));
  };

  const envelopeOpen = () => {
    setEnvOpen(true);
  };

  const envelopeClose = () => {
    setEnvOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOpen[1]) {
      document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollDetect);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen[1]) {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollDetect);
    }
  }, [isOpen]);
```

**UPDATE: repo here**
https://github.com/erasebegin/portfolio-2020

Created using create-react-app so just `npm/yarn start`

Comment: Your function may technically have a name, but, that's doesn't absolve it from the same problem using an anonymous function causes. if you're creating the function that you're passing to removeEventListener in a different context than the function that was used to add it, it's a different function, regardless of whether or not they share name/sourcecode.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin, I didn't think about that at all. Unfortunately changing to a regular function didn't fix the problem T_T

Comment: Right, but, if you're still creating that regular function, where you're creating the one righ now, it's the same problem. The function that you are passing to remove, isn't the same one you passed to add. They may be equivalent, but they aren't exactly equal.

Comment: My guess would be that you your second effect is for some reason executing before your first, but it's hard to tell. Could you try passing both `isOpen` and `scroll` detect as dependencies (inside the second argument array) to both of your `useEffect`s? You could also add a log statement to the end of each effect, so you can tell which is executing first. Feel free to update after you get more info and I'll see if I can help! 

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply ^_^ What do you mean when you say I should add "scroll" as a dependency? Do you mean the `scrollDetect` function? If I add that to the dependency array I get a warning in VSCode that I should wrap `scrollDetect` in a `useCallback` hook.

Comment: Hmm, I would say try moving the function out of the scope of the Nav react functional component?

Comment: Hi Pandamakes, do you mean move it to the parent component? Because if I keep it in the same file and just move it outside of the functional component I don't know how I could affect the state of the functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an "if" statement at the first useEffect.

just to make sure its not adding the event listener, again.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect1")
    console.log(isOpen[1]);
    if(!isOpen)
       document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollDetect);
  }, []);
```

**Update as well**

We can use "useCallback" to keep a reference to the same function object, this way we are making sure that we are using the same function, give it a shot.

```
const scrollDetect = useCallback(() => {
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("show");
    } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("hide");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
},[]);
```

annnnnd lets hope it works this time

Comment: Tried this too and it didn't work T_T thanks anyway, I really appreciate your response ^_^

Comment: useCallback is interesting, I've not seen it before. But would I use it instead of useEffect? or alongside useEffect? I swapped out the scrollDetect function for your code and it seems to stop the scrollDetect code from running entirely

Comment: Yes you just swap it with the function itself, sorry there was a typo in the code, maybe try now?, it should at least work

Comment: Still no luck. With useCallback it just stops the scrollDetect function from running.

Comment: it seems u changed the code a bit, can u add also the isOpen as a dependency for the first useEffect, if that doesn't work too, then i suggest you push your code somewhere we can edit, so we can attempt to fix it

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't change anything. It's weird actually, even if I give the `removeEventListener` `useEffect` _no dependencies_, which should mean it's being called every rerender, and then give the `addEventListener` `useEffect` a dependency of `isOpen[1]`, the event listener is still not being removed! So even when `removeEventListener` is being called way more often than `addEventListener`, it doesn't have any effect.....

Anyway, I added the repo to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollDetect` is arrow function and you create new function for each render of your component.
in removeEventLister you need to pass the same function that you used in addEventListener. But it'll never happen)

For such thing you can write it as function

```
  function scrollDetect() {
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("show");
    } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("hide");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
  };
```

or you can init this function in your useEffect)

***UPDATE***
Did you try like that?

```
...
function scrollDetect(){
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("show");
    } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      setScrollState("hide");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
  };

  const setOpen = ([title, state]) => {
    let newState = !state;
    setIsOpen([title, newState]);
  };

  const setHeight = (title, height) => {
    setPanelHeight((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [title]: height }));
  };

  const envelopeOpen = () => {
    setEnvOpen(true);
  };

  const envelopeClose = () => {
    setEnvOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect1")
    console.log(isOpen[1]);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollDetect);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect2")
    console.log(isOpen[1]);
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollDetect);
  }, [isOpen]);
...
```

Comment: This is **such** a great answer, I never think of arrow functions as assigning anonymous functions, I always just think of them the same as functions! But... it didn't work T_T Such a perfect answer and somehow the problem remains!

Thank you for trying boikov

Comment: Also, I can't init the function in useEffect because then removeEventListener in the second useEffect doesn't have access to the scrollDetect. I used to have them both in the same useEffect, but was advised to separate them on another post. Maybe I should try combining them again...

Comment: I updated my answer to see if you wrote the same code as i did) Anyway if you still have a problem you can attach sandbox sample with source code)

Comment: Thank you again :) that is exactly how I wrote the code, but it didn't have any effect. I will try to create a sandbox tomorrow as it's very late and I should get some sleep. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no answer. Nothing has worked. I am going to repost this, hopefully in a more coherent way and see if anyone can help. Thank you everyone for your responses.